# Ember unit test for application route failing

Tags: ember.js

I am an ember nube. I have retraced the steps in the Ember tutorial and taken a very gentle detour to add bootstrap with an authentication flow. Somewhere along the way I added the application route. The generator made this:

```
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleFor('route:application', 'Unit | Route | application', {
  // Specify the other units that are required for this test.
  // needs: ['controller:foo']
});

test('it exists', function(assert) {
  let route = this.subject();
  assert.ok(route);
});
```

app/routes/application.js looks like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin);
```

It is bombing. I have done some sleuthing, but I am too new to find the cause of my woe in the stack trace below. I could of course just blow off the error, but I have the feeling I am going to be doing the same blunder again, and would like to not weaken the test cases. Does anyone know what I am missing in my application-test.js?

```
Unit | Route | application: it exists (1, 0, 1)Rerun39 ms
Died on test #1     at testWrapper (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:7162:11)
    at test (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:7176:39)
    at Module.callback (http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:367:24)
    at Module.exports (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:132:32)
    at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:32:18)
    at Object.TestLoader.require (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6942:7)
    at Object.loadModules (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6934:14): Cannot read property 'on' of undefined@ 22 ms
Source:     
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:151286:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Class._subscribeToSessionEvents (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:151280:131)
    at Class.init (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:151273:12)
    at Class.superWrapper [as init] (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:35502:22)
    at new Class (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:48214:14)
    at Function.create (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:48485:14)
    at Object.defaultSubject (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:8362:22)
    at Object.context.(anonymous function) [as subject] (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:8394:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:368:22)
Source: at testWrapper (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:7162:11) at test (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:7176:39) at Module.callback (http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:367:24) at Module.exports (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:132:32) at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:32:18) at Object.TestLoader.require (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6942:7) at Object.loadModules (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6934:14)
```

Comment: Are there codes already in the application route?

Comment: @MikkoPaderes, my application.js route looks like << edited above>>

Comment: Try adding `needs: ['service:session']`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your application route is doing, I can't be sure, but here are a couple of possibilities:

It looks like there is code calling a jquery on, on an object that hasn't been defined.

You could've imported a 3rd party library that's not yet available to your tests (like if you've included a script in your index.html), or you could have environment-specific assets ( https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_environment-specific-assets )

You also might need to include a dependency in your "needs" block.  Things ordinarily loaded from the container like ember data objects, services, and controllers need to be specified in the needs block for unit tests.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the OP to include the route. I see a commented out "needs" block in the generated test, and can see examples of the syntax, but I am at a loss on what exactly it is needing. I did add some simple-auth stuff. Maybe it is "needy" there?

Comment: yes, most likely.  Your "needs" block specifies to the test things loaded from the ember container.  So for example, if your class under test injected a service (which it might be with simple auth), then you would specify "service:<your-svc-name>" as a need.  This will tell the test framework to provide that service  when asked for.  the documentation for ember-qunit has some more details which need to be fed back into the guides: https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/blob/master/README.md